# Weird VS2013 conflict with a "[dynamic]" file vs the normal file

Tags: javascript, file, dynamic, visual-studio-2013, edit

In my javascript/html project, I have a js file that throws an exception because of an undefined name. But I have corrected this problem and saved the file with the fix. In edit mode the fix is visible. Yet when I run the project to test, the exception still happens, only it is shown as being in another file in the preview tab with the tab labeled as "filename.js[dynamic]". This other file is the same as my copy of "filename.js", except for the missing correction that I just added.

I have restarted VS and also restarted the computer, but this still happens. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Duh! Yes. I cleared my cache and it fixed this problem. That whole presentation of a [dynamic] version was something I had never seen.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem as well and was able to fix it by just exiting IISExpress and re-starting my webapp.

Comment: this answer does address the question.